# clang-r433403 SantizerCoverage issue

Tags: android, linux-kernel, llvm, lto

I trying to compile Linux kernel with GCOV flag via "clang-r433403",
Unfortunately, I'm getting a similar issue like [here](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39531) ,
I found the root cause bug and the [patch](https://reviews.llvm.org/rG4914c9836765532ffaec9c85bc57690dbdaeb50f) too.

My question is how can I download "llvm" source with same revision ("clang-r433403") to apply the patch and build ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do this. Patch is in clang 13, so you could simply use the latest released clang.